# Make asynchronous call synchronous in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have an API I have no control over.... which contains a method that does some work and returns the results asynchronously. I would like to call this method synchronously in parts of my application. I have done this by adding a class `ResultHandler` which captures and returns the result. Is there a better way of doing this than the way I've done it below? Perhaps using standard kotlin (or Java as last resort) library methods. My preference would be for  `awaitReply` to return the result and also to remove the `CountdownLatch`.

```
class Main {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic

        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val result1 = Main().nonAsyncMethod1(arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            result1.elements.forEach { println(it) }
        }
    }

    class Result1(var elements: Collection<String>)

    fun asyncMethod1(x: Collection<Int>, callback: (Result1) -> Unit) {
        Thread().run {
            // do some calculation
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            callback(Result1(x.map { "\"$it\"" }.toList()))
        }
    }

    private fun nonAsyncMethod1(entities: Collection<Int>): Result1 {
        val resultHandler = ResultHandler<Result1>()

        awaitReply<Result1> {
            asyncMethod1(entities, resultHandler)
        }
        return resultHandler.getResponse()
    }

    open class ResultHandler<T : Any> : (T) -> Unit {
        private lateinit var response: T
        private val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

        override fun invoke(response: T) {
            latch.countDown()
            this.response = response
        }

        fun getResponse(): T {
            latch.await()
            return response
        }
    }

    private fun <T : Any> awaitReply(call: () -> Unit) {
        return call.invoke()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use Kotlin Coroutines async call together with await() function?

Comment: Rather than a CountdownLatch, I would try a Future object

Comment: @the_dani Thanks for the suggestions. Is there an example of the approach you're suggesting in the Kotlin docs? I had a look earlier but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from the_dani

I managed come to the solution below using coroutines as detailed in "[Wrapping callbacks](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks)" section of the Kotlin coroutines documentation:

```
class Main {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic

        fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
            val result1 = Main().nonAsyncMethod1(arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            result1.elements.forEach { println(it) }
        }
    }

    class Result1(var elements: Collection<String>)

    fun asyncMethod1(x: Collection<Int>, callback: (Result1) -> Unit) {
        Thread().run {
            // do some calculation
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            callback(Result1(x.map { "\"$it\"" }.toList()))
        }
    }

    suspend fun nonAsyncMethod1(entities: Collection<Int>): Result1 = suspendCoroutine {
        cont ->
            asyncMethod1(entities) { cont.resume(it) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap async functions with a callback with coroutines
(Coroutines are similar to C# async/await, you can create asynchronous code that looks very much synchronous, but which is executed asynchronous)

https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks

> There is a simple pattern. Assume that you have someLongComputation
>   function with callback that receives some Value that is a result of
>   this computation.
>
> ```
> fun someLongComputation(params: Params, callback: (Value) -> Unit)`
> ```
>
> You can convert it into a suspending function with the following
>   straightforward code:
>
> ```
> suspend fun someLongComputation(params: Params): Value = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
>     someLongComputation(params) { cont.resume(it) } 
> }
> ```

Suspend functions can only be called in a coroutine context (for example with `launch{ }`), but in order to wait you can use [`runBlocking{ }`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) which should then wait for the coroutine to finish. This should create your desired behaviour.